# Problems Installing Gulp

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gulp

I'm trying to get Gulp to work on my Ubuntu system. When I run the command to install Gulp, no errors are reported, but running `gulp -v` after installation, for example, doesn't work.

npm -v 2.11.3

nodejs -v 0.10.25

[image: Here's the message I get when I try to install]

Comment: Try closing and reopening your shell. Also, maybe you need to do sudo gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add PATH to your profile (~/bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc or ~/.profile).

> export PATH=$PATH:{your_node_home}/bin

then source it from your shell

> source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot implies that you're installing `gulp` as the *root* user in a *root-user-specific folder* (`/root/npm/bin`), which you shouldn't, because it's likely not in your `$PATH`.

If you're installing Node.js and global npm packages *system-wide*, it should be in a *user-independent* location such as `/usr` (Ubuntu) or `/usr/local` (OS X).

- This is what the official installers / package-manager packages - which *do* require `sudo` - do; they ensure that `node`, `npm`, and CLIs from globally installed npm packages are automatically placed in the `$PATH`, given that folders such as `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are contained in `$PATH`.

Alternatively, if you've performed a *user-level* install of Node.js to begin with, such as with [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) or [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), run `npm` commands as *yourself*.

`npm get prefix` will tell you the *parent* folder of the `bin` folder that CLIs will be placed in on global installation.

In other words: **you'll only be able to execute CLIs from globally installed npm packages globally (by their mere *filenames*, such as `gulp`), if `$(npm get prefix)/bin` is in your `$PATH`.**

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm a begginer running a linux and Ethan told me how to set up the variables and it solved my problem. Even though I appreciate your help.

Comment: I just don't get how should I install gulp with no root permission.

Comment: I probally installed with npm as root. (It needs 15 of reputation and it looks like I dont have enought to upvote).

Comment: @Wellyngton: See if my updated answer helps; re up-vote: no worries (and thanks for reminding me of the limit), just wanted you to know in general.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your `node_modules/.bin` is not in your `$PATH`.

Try to put it on your `$PATH` and try again. :)